# Switched from tableview to colelctionview now didselectitematindexpath not called

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, didselectrowatindexpath

So I switched from a UITableView to a UICollectionView.  The cells are all loading just fine and look beautiful, but now I can no longer select any of them. The taps are recognized in the logs, but it doesn't take me to the view that it's supposed to take me to anymore.

The only things that changed really are the ones the ones you see commented out in the "cellForItem" section. Everything else is identical to how it was when it was working in the TableView. It's just supposed to take me to the ViewController specified when you tap. Instead the tap is recorded, but it does nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Also I tried getting rid of the [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

...but it didn't make any difference.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        PlaceCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    //UINib * placeCell = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Shops" bundle:nil];
   // NSArray *topLevelItems = [placeCell instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];      

   // cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];

    Place *p = [_entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.placeName.text = p.PName;
    NSLog(@"p:%@",p.PName);
    cell.placeName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:3/255.0f green:6/255.0f blue:4/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    NSString *pIcon;
    pIcon = typeName;
    //NSLog(pIcon);
    cell.placeImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:p.PImage]]];
    NSLog(@"i:%@",p.PImage);
    return cell;
}

-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"Tap Recognized");
    [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    Place *p = [_entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DetailPlaceViewController * pvc = [[DetailPlaceViewController alloc] init];
    [pvc setPlace:p];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this one was fun...

For some odd reason my navigation controller isn't working... so of course using the navigation controller to load a view wasn't going to work. Simple enough solution... load the view without the navigation controller. I was just going to delete this question, but maybe somebody might be in a similar situation one day:

```
[self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```